# Version Control System

Tags: linux, git, subversion, version-control

In our company we use Subversion for version control system. Now if there is a folder of 10GB in the server and 4 users are working in the project, then during checkout it will accumlate 40GB's of data which is unnecessary since the users are going to use only certain files in different directories. Is there any way to make it as a memory efficient one or we can go for another VC tool

Comment: 80GBs (no apostrophe). Are you all on the same machine?

Comment: What do you mean by "4 users are working in the project"? Do they checkouts or commits or ...? Please give examples of your commands.

Answer (score 4):

Even with Subversion, `svn update` (see `svn help update`) should only transfer the changed files. You can also use `svn checkout <path>` (see `svn help checkout`) to only checkout subdirectories.

I'm not sure how the repository grew to 10 GB. A repository is for **source** files, i.e. human readable text. If you managed to produce 10 GB of human readable text, that's quite a lot for 4 users...

Binary files **don't** belong in a repository. And using a repository to track databases is not going to work.

So I really suspect what you need to do is to change how you use the repository, not find another version control system.

Answer (score 1):

Follow-up to @dirkt

1. "NNN GBs" on server-side is size of **repository** with **all history**
2. When everybody checkout repo, he get only *slice* - one revision
3. If even ingle revision is "too much" and only small subset of files have to be changed, every developer can checkout only part of repository tree, starting from nearest common ancestor of required files
4. Subsequent `svn ci` and `svn up` will require a lot less volumes ащк цщкл